# Trouble synchronously receiving messages from Queue in Websphere 6.1

Tags: java, jms, websphere

I have trouble developing JMS application with Websphere 6.1.0.33 with EJB 3.0 FP.

Application has two queues - RequestQueue and ResponseQueue. 
An MDB is attached to RequestQueue to process messages via Session bean and to post responses in ResponseQueue.
Servlet is used as a testing client. It has two options - to send a request to RequestQueue and to synchronously receive response via MessageConsumer.receiveNoWait.
The problem is that receiveNoWait always return null - even if there are messages is queue (i can see 'em through AdminConsole). MessageConsumer.receive blocks forever.
Moreover, if I attach MDB to listen to ResponseQueue, it will work ok and receive all the responses.

SIB is used as the messaging engine, there are two destinations linked to queues.
For each MDB there is an Activation Specification configured.

I double-checked all bindings and still can't see the problem.

Specifying trace as in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199176 gives no useful data.

Maybe I left out some configuration component?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand your exact setup based on your description, but if I understand correctly your servlet is connecting to the ResponseQueue explicitly (creating a MessageConsumer based on a "normal" JMS connection rather than a JCA/activation profile binding). This would be a problem if you also have an activation profile configured for the ResponseQueue as the activation profile would "take over" consumption of the queue. Make sure that you remove any activation profile for ResponseQueue if you intend to consume it manually.

Comment: yep, Servlet connects explicitly via `session.createConsumer(queue).receiveNoWait()`.
Queue and ConnectionFactory are injected via `@Resource` and have bindings configured in deployment descriptor.
Also, what is JCA/activation profile binding setup for a servlet? Use a MessageListener?

Comment: I removed all the Activation Specifications for the `ResponseQueue` but it had no effect. Nevertheless, the idea of them "taking over" seems plausible.

Comment: Well, the fact that you still cant receive messages indicates some type of configuration error. Could you update your question with the code of your servlet as well as the content your web.xml and ibm-web-bnd.xmi files. If you are using Spring, please include relevant parts of your application context configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Case solved!

Missed `connection.start()` call.

Thanks @pap for your help =).

Should pay more attention to docs next time.

Comment: Congrats :) Good luck going forward.